# linkbutton open new page and pass value without using query string and session

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, linkbutton

I'm working the linkbutton in a **nested masterpage** and want to pass a value to a new page .

What I want to do is once I click the link button. a new page will be open and keep the 
current page. in the same time, i can pass a value to the new open page.

how can I do without using Query String and session?

Thanks

Comment: When you said 'new page will be open and keep the current page' did you want to say that the new page opens in new window (not a simple task, since LinkButton performs a postback), or you ment that the new page uses the same master page?

Comment: hi, Goran. Ya, it is open a new page but the current page will keep. for example. the current page is page1.aspx but once i click the linkbutton the page2.aspx will be open in new tab and page1.aspx will not close.

Comment: hi, Goran.  i had read a lot of other article. do u think is it possible that i use hyperlink to open a new page with passing a value too? ya,without session and querystring.

Comment: You could use PreviousPageType directive in new page to access public properties on previous page, but I don't think it would work if your link is on masterpage (so it could be clicked from any page using this master).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the HTML of the new page, you can include a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldname" value="your value">
```

Comment: hi, Dennis, i had read a lot of other article. do u think is it possible that i use hyperlink to open a new page with passing a value too? ya,without session and querystring.